# I have a bit of Englishman in me

Tags: idioms

You would say 'I have a bit of the English in me' to say 'I have a bit of English 'blood/heritage/temperament.'

Would the following be also used?
**I have a bit of Englishman in me.**

Comment: If you want to use something even more idiomatic, "I have a *touch* of the English in me". (This one does not work at all with "Englishman".)

Answer (score 1):

The common expression uses *English*, not *Englishman*, and would more commonly not use the article:

> I have a bit of English in me.
>   I have a bit of *the* English in me.

Without the article, there is more association with the generic idea (mass noun) than there is with something specific.

Using the definite article sounds *slightly* strange because it gives the noun more of a specific quality—almost as if you were referring to some collective people living inside of you rather than the idea of cultural heritage.

---

But with *Englishman*, if you were to use that word, I'd say the situation is reversed, where the use of the article would sound more natural—simply because of what that particular noun represents:

> I have a bit of *the* Englishman in me.
>   I have a bit of Englishman in me.

As opposed to English, which is more of a generic idea (or mass noun) without the article, the word Englishman is more of a specific noun, something which commonly requires some kind of article.

Note that using the indefinite article would sound almost as strange as using no article at all (although in a different way):

> I have a big of *an* Englishman in me.

It's still fine, as a figurative expression, and might be taken in a comic way if used for effect. (But also possibly misinterpreted in that way.)

---

As a general answer, *Englishman* might be fine in some context. But if you're not sure, it's safer to stick to *English* or *English blood* or *English heritage*.

Comment: I disagree that "a bit of the English" is unnatural. "A bit of the Irish" sounds much more natural to me than "a bit of Irish".

Comment: @PatrickStevens I didn't say it was unnatural. I said it sounded *slightly* strange. I imagine it's also particular to region and dialect. Also *a bit of the Irish* is very specific and almost an idiom—it sounds different than *a bit of the Russian,* because the latter isn't one that's heard all the time.

Comment: Does that mean 'a bit of Russian' is more often heard?

Comment: @Sssamy To me, *I have a bit of Russian in me* sounds like it would be more common. But these are not phrases that can easily be searched to determine anything objective.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfortunate "double meaning". Having "a bit of Englishman in you" can be used as the punchline of a "dirty" joke.

The better way to say this is "I'm part English". (To mean "I have an English ancestor")